# How to pass query params in Map Local/Remote in Charles Debugger

Tags: fiddler, charles-proxy

I am used to using Fiddler, but have recently purchased a Mac and am forced to use Charles.  I have successfully mapped some web requests to files on another web server, but I cannot get the query params to pass through.  In fiddler I use something like regex:www.example.com(/w*) in the from and everything works as expected, however I cannot for the life of me find how to do this in Charles.  Any help or direction would be great!  TIA!

Comment: FWIW, you can run Fiddler in Parallels/Fusion/VirtualBox or on Mono (http://fiddler.wikidot.com/mono) on the Mac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't believe this but apparently all I had to do was place an asterisk in the from query param box and it seems to be passing it through.  Was easier than Fiddler...no regex needed.